# ReactJS is giving bad set state error in useMemo function

Tags: reactjs

I have this `useMemo` which Is used for searching data

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";

import "./SearchCharacters.css";

function SearchCharacters({ charactersInfo, setSearchResult }) {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  useMemo(() => {
    const findCharacter = charactersInfo.filter((character) => {
      return (
        character.gender.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase() ||
        character.species.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase() ||
        character.status.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase()
      );
    });

    findCharacter.length > 0
      ? setSearchResult(findCharacter)
      : setSearchResult(null);
  }, [searchText]);
  return (
    <div className="search_container">
      <input
        className="search_input"
        onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter characters full name"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchCharacters;
```

`charactersInfo` - Is an array of object which contains information about characters
`setSearchResult` - Is an setState which  I am passing from parent component

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Characters`) while rendering a different component (`SearchCharacters`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `SearchCharacters`, follow the stack trace
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Define "bad state error", what's the issue exactly? `charactersInfo` is missing from the dependencies array of `useMemo`

Comment: it literally says bad setState in SearchCharacters component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're confusing useMemo with useEffect. useMemo is a function returning a memoised value & not intended for running side-effects like you are doing at the end. so do this:

```
const characters = useMemo(() => {
return charactersInfo.filter((character) => {
  return (
    character.gender.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase() ||
    character.species.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase() ||
    character.status.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase()
  );
});
}, [searchText]);
```

and then in response to change of characters, run the effects like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
characters.length > 0
      ? setSearchResult(findCharacter)
      : setSearchResult(null);
}, [characters])
```

Answer (score 6):

You should not do any `setState` in a `useMemo`. It should be an idempotent operation, and it should not contain any side effect. You typically want to use `useMemo` when you need to compute something heavy, and you want to memoize the result, which it doesn't seem the case here.

Replace `useMemo` with `useEffect`. Also, be careful on providing `charactersInfo` in the dependency array.

Comment: but won't useEffect be overkill when doing search functionality?

Comment: You want to run side effects when the search text change. useEffect is the right place for that kind of operations.